# Shopware 6 Show Custom Error Message In StoreFront by javascript

Tags: shopware, shopware6

i need to show the error message in storefront in shopware 6 by using js.

import Plugin from 'src/plugin-system/plugin.class';

export default class Product extends Plugin {
in this we need to set error message  and show the storefront
}

Answer (score 0):

Messages in Shopware6 are based on [Symfony Flash Messages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html#flash-messages), which are being added to the `app` variable from PHP and are accessible in twig.
In addition to being accessible only from backend side, they are also removed from the session as soon as they have been accessed (for example in a loop)

As far as I'm aware, there's no built-in feature to show such messages via JavaScript.

So you would have to either add the message via PHP and show/hide it from JavaScript, or completely add the message via JavaScript as a new HTML element to the page.